# How can I validate a web page's markup programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, html, regex, validation

I need to validate a web page markup programmatically and I heard it's possible by using regular expressions. If so how? Is there any other way? (Other than using w3c service)

Comment: hehe reminded me of my favourite question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags .

Comment: It's definitely not a problem to be solved with regular expressions (see Zortkun's link), but obviously it _is_ possible in other ways or the w3c's service wouldn't exist...

Comment: whats wrong about using the w3c service? it's authoritative and can be [queried programmatically](http://validator.w3.org/docs/users.html#Calling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTML Tidy http://tidy.sourceforge.net/  It both reports on the validity of an HTML document, and can attempt to automatically clean it up.  You can run it as a command line application and script it.  There are ports or wrappers for it in Java, Perl, and Python.

I also use TagSoup library for Java http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/  It does a great job of cleaning up badly formatted HTML into valid XML.